# AwsClientBuilder Gradle?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am working on using the Amazon SNS service to send notifications to the device. I have some code that I am basing it off of that I wrote back at the begining of the year. However it seems like one of the functions I use `AmazonSNSClient client = new AmazonSNSClient(credentialsProvider);` is now depricated according to the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html). It says instead to use  `AwsClientBuilder.withCredentials(AWSCredentialsProvider)` However when I put this in, it is not recognized.

What do I need to put into my gradle file to use AwsClinetBuilder?

Comment: Are you doing Android development or something else?

Comment: Android development.

Comment: Annnd. This is where I realize my mistake in assuming that their Java implentation is the same as their Android one. Doh! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was based on the wrong documentation. Correct documentation can be found here.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/